# I give you some metal, and you steal my name!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*It was hard to expand on this riddle while maintaining the single rhymes, so it is much easier than expected to solve...Hopefully you enjoy the rhymes*:

> I give you some metal, and you steal my name! 
> I had to have known,
>   I am only to blame.
>
> Even when right I'm wrong, what a shame. 
> A sacrifice I make, to
>   help in my claim.
>
> I will waiver my rights, and steady my aim. 
> For my resistance is
>   futile, within my time frame.
>
> A quick easy answer can give you some fame. 
> So find what I am, and
>   finish this game!

---

*If you enjoyed this riddle, some of my other rhyming riddles can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brhyme%5D%20user%3A11244%20is%3Aquestion)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the answer

> Male

I give you some metal, and you steal my name!

> Fe (iron) + male = female. Can also refer to how after the man gives his woman a wedding ring, she takes his last name.

I had to have known, I am only to blame.

> Women always blame men. Also, men often give precious metals to women like gold and silver. **EDIT:** Men are usually the ones to propose marriage.

Even when right I'm wrong, what a shame.

> Women are always right! :P

A sacrifice I make, to help in my claim.

> Men often let women win arguments to keep the relationship steady.

I will waiver my rights, and steady my aim.

> Men get married and give up the merriment of their bachelor life.

For my resistance is futile, within my time frame.

> Women keep pestering men to commit and get married. **EDIT:** Once they are married, there is no escape and trying to resist is not generally a good idea.

A quick easy answer can give you some fame. 
So find what I am, and finish this game!

> Can I haz some repz?

Comment: You are close! I was thinking along similar lines...(your answer has some of my intentions inside)

Comment: I think you might be able to improve/edit your 2nd and 6th line answers. (In comparison to my 'ideal answer')

Comment: @MarkN Did you just have a fight with your wife/girlfriend?

Comment: @mmking, lets just say, someone has increased my family size recently [which is the source of 'inspiration' behind this riddle] :p

Comment: 'I had to have known, I am only to blame.' Does this have something to do with the fact that men often pursue women?

Comment: @CodeNewbie As for my suggested answer: #2) If one gave away the 'metal' then it was their intentions to start such an event. (So they are the cause of this 'event'). #6) Once the 'event' completes, one can not simply escape (and the time-frame is quite long).

Comment: @CodeNewbie, I had attempted to keep this riddle as gender neutral as possible. (and avoid most stereotypes)

Comment: My intended answer was marriage, but it seems this answer can be just as suitable.